# Django multi field filtering in POST

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a Restaurant table with fields such as cuisine_type and outlet_type, which cuisine_type has a Cuisine table(pk, cuisine_type) and outlet_type has a Outlet table(pk, outlet_type). There is more fields such as is_vegeterian_friendly, affordability and so on. User is free to pick any field they want to cast the filter and I don't wish to create a combination of the fields to handle each request. That is madness.

User can apply filter on any field in a POST request's body as below:

```
{
    "outlet_type":  1, 
    "cuisine_type": 2,
    ...
}
```

The view will return a list of restaurants after the filter

```
class RestaurantList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        filter = dict(request.data)
        retaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(**filter)
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(retaurants, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

However, when there is multiple choice under one field, for instance, they want to filter multiple cuisine_type such as 1 and 2, then the request's body have to add __in in order to make it works.

```
{
    "outlet_type":  1, 
    "cuisine_type__in": [1, 2],
    ...
}
```

Any better way to do it? I am expecting that we don't need to alter the key name and we just make the value as array such as:

```
{
    "outlet_type":  1, 
    "cuisine_type": [1, 2],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) package ? If so, it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-filter) lib for filtering. It is quite simple to use and provides a range of filtering options.

For your case, you could start with something like this:

```
class RestaurantFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    #use appropriate field names below.
    outlet_type = django_filters.CharFilter(name="outlet_type", lookup_type="contains")
    cuisine_type = django_filters.CharFilter(name="cuisine_type", lookup_type="contains")

class Meta:
    model = Restaurant
```